# Creating YAML for Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, doctrine-orm, yaml

I've seen a [plugin](http://code.google.com/p/mysql-workbench-doctrine-plugin/) for MySQL Workbench for exporting schema's in YAML format.  But, it no longer appears to be supported.

I'll be trying to Doctrine 2.0 and would be interested in any suggestions or best practices for writing the designing the YAML, DB, and Models.

From what I can tell so far, it seems that these are the available options:

1. Hand write YAML and use this to generate the Models. The models will then issue the appropriate create table scripts to build the MySQL tables.
2. Use an editor to build YAML files, continue as above.
3. Build the database (using WorkBench or by hand), then use `Doctrine_Core::generateModelsFromDb()` to build the models.  This I assume would remove the need for YAML?

Am I missing anything? Would love to hear any tips/feedback from those who have a lot more experience with ORM/Doctrine2.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ad 1. I try this, but I can't imagine build bigger database with relations in YAML.

ad 2. Try http://www.orm-designer.com/. For small db is ok, but for bigger with many relations are problems.

ad 3. `Doctrine_Core::generateModelsFromDb()` exists in Doctrine1. For Doctrine2 try [console tools](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/tools.html).

I make a lot in Doctrine1, but new projects prepare in Doctrine2.
I lost some time looking better way to create entities, but nothing better founded, so I do:

1. Create database in Workbench
2. Synchronize to local database
3. Create Doctrine entities from database

Comment: Sounds good to me.  Thanks, I will try that approach.

Comment: I just want to notice that we renamed ORM Designer3 to Skipper and now the application is available here [www.skipper18.com](http://www.skipper18.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can use our tool [Skipper - formerly ORM Designer](http://www.skipper18.com/)  to skip hand writing of the YAML schemas altogether (I'm chief developer of this tool).

You can design your entities, relations and modules in visual environment and have the schema files generated automatically by ORM Designer. Then you will let Doctrine to generate the database.

The visual model is readable and fast enough to build models for large databases from scratch and work with them.